# Query to filter duplicate rows for particular column values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below table with given values:-

```
create or Replace table CourseLibrary (
    Parent_code varchar(250),
    Parent_Name varchar(250),
    Course_Version varchar(250),
    Course_Locale varchar(250),
    Timestamp varchar(250)
);

Insert into Courselibrary values
('UXPUEMBR007', 'Back Injury Prevention', '1.0.004', 'en_US', '3'),
('UXPUEMBR007', 'Back Injury Prevention2', '1.0.002', 'en_US',  '4'),
('UXPUEMBR007', 'Back Injury Prevention1', '1.0.004', 'en_BR', '5'),
('UXPUEMBR007', 'Back Injury Prevention', '1.0.003', 'en_US', '2'),
('UXPUEMBR007', 'Back Injury Prevention', '1.0.004', 'en_US', '1'),
('UXPUEMBR008', 'House Safety', '1.0.006', 'en_US', '1'),
('UXPUEMBR008', 'House Safety', '1.0.005', 'en_US', '1'),
('UXPUEMBR008', 'House Safety', '1.0.006', 'en_US', '2');
```

Need query to filter Below ResultSet:

```
('UXPUEMBR007', 'Back Injury Prevention', '1.0.004', 'en_US', '3')
 ('UXPUEMBR008', 'House Safety', '1.0.006', 'en_US', '2')
```

I need a single row for a given Parent_code. If there are multiple Parent_code, then I have to look for highest Course_Version, if even Course_version's are same, then I have to look for course_locale=’en_US’ only. And if even course_locale are same, then lastly I have to check for highest timestamp value.

Note: No primary key

Priority:-1st highest course_version, 2nd course_locale=’en_US’, 3rd timestamp

Comment: There are some smart quotes in here, making actual intent indecipherable. I advise you to not use Word, or similar, as your code text editor. And please identify your PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: What is your version of MySQL?

Comment: MYSQL version 5.7

Comment: The answer that you accepted does not work in MySql 5.7!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1:

```
WITH top_records AS (SELECT PARENT_CODE, PARENT_NAME, Course_Version, Course_Locale, Timestamp, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PARENT_CODE ORDER BY Course_Version DESC, Timestamp DESC) RN FROM Courselibrary WHERE Course_Locale = 'en_US') Select * from top_records where RN = 1;
```

Solution 2:

```
Select PARENT_CODE, PARENT_NAME, Course_Version, Course_Locale, Timestamp from (SELECT PARENT_CODE, PARENT_NAME, Course_Version, Course_Locale, Timestamp, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PARENT_CODE ORDER BY Course_Version DESC, Timestamp DESC) RN FROM Courselibrary WHERE Course_Locale = 'en_US') Where RN = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8+, you would use `row_number()`.  In earlier versions, you can use a correlated subquery -- but this assumes that you have a unique identifier on each row.  So, define your table as:

```
create table CourseLibrary (
    CourseLibrary_Id int auto_increment primary key,
    Parent_code varchar(250),
    Parent_Name varchar(250),
    Course_Version varchar(250),
    Course_Locale varchar(250),
    Timestamp varchar(250)
);
```

I also think that something called a `timestamp` should be stored as a date/time value, NOT as string.

Then you can do:

```
select cl.*
from CourseLibrary cl
where cl.CourseLibrary_Id = (select cl2.CourseLibrary_Id
                             from CourseLibrary cl2
                             where cl2.Parent_code = cl.Parent_code
                             order by Course_Version desc,
                                      (course_locale = 'en_US') desc,
                                      timestamp desc
                             limit 1
                            );
```

You don't really need `CourseLibrary_Id`.  Any primary key will do.  However, your table doesn't have one, so an auto-incremented id is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(timestamp) as timestamp, parent_code, parent_name, course_version, course_locale from (select * from courselibrary where parent_code='UXPUEMBR007' and (select count(*) from courselibrary where parent_code='UXPUEMBR007') >= 1 and course_version=(select max(course_version) from courselibrary where parent_code='UXPUEMBR007') and course_locale='en_US') as resultset group by parent_code, parent_name, course_version, course_locale;
```